# What is the correct way to call the Obspy trace filter function?

Tags: filter, time-series, obspy

I am trying to bandpass filter a trace (loaded correctly) using

```
tr.filter('bandpass', freqmin, freqmax, df, corners=corners, zerophase=False)
```

Unfortunately this returns:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nm_data_analysis.py", line 44, in <module>
    tr.filter('bandpass', freqmin, freqmax, df, corners=corners, zerophase=False) # Bandpass filter data
TypeError: filter() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given`

The relevant documentation can be found [here](https://docs.obspy.org/packages/autogen/obspy.core.trace.Trace.filter.html#obspy.core.trace.Trace.filter)

Please let me know if you can see where I am going wrong.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the frequencies as keyword arguments. This is a (potentially unfortunate) consequence of its API.

```py
import obspy
tr = obspy.read()[0]
tr.filter("bandpass", freqmin=1.0, freqmax=10.0,
          corners=2, zerophase=False)
```